# How to model this domain? DDD

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

In the domain that i'm trying to model, there are 2 classes: ClothingType and TreatmentType

```
public class ClothingType : Entity<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    public ClothingType(Guid id, string name)
        : base (id)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class TreatmentType : Entity<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    public TreatmentType(Guid id, string name)
        : base(id)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

A ClothingType (t-shirt, pant, etc) support many kinds of TreatmentType's (wash, iron, etc). And one kind of TreatmentType can be supported by many ClothingType's. But, the price of a specified TreatmentType varies according to ClothingType.

Imagine two kinds of treatments: wash and iron. In t-shirts, washing costs $20, in pants costs $35, and so on. How to model this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can identify two bounded contexts: Clothing and Ordering with anti-corruption layer between them

Comment: I have a TreatmentOrder class belonging to the ClothesTreatment bounded-context (but it make sense belonging to ClothesTreatmentOrdering): https://pastebin.com/NRF1QxQp

Comment: don't think about classes until you correctly identify the bounded contexts. Are you sure about that (ClothesTreatmentOrdering???)? Ordering bc can be easily a generic sub-domain and implemented using an off-the-shell solution.

Answer (score 1):

Clothing type and Entity Type are probably values, rather than entities.

There might be a product catalog, or some analog to it, with query methods that take a clothing type and an entity type as inputs and provide a pricing estimate as an output.  If you needed that pricing estimate in your domain logic, then you would likely achieve that via a domain service that allowed the model to access a recent copy of the product catalog to look up the pricing.

Comment: I'm modeling a domain for a laundry. There's no product catalog. But nevertheless, that's a great ideia, the price will have to come in database. So, how to handle this in a domain service? They can't have any knowledge about persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Alberto Brandolini's Event Storming approach so you could discover the domain you're dealing with. Is billing part of your core bounded context?

If it's just a usual ecommerce product with a price, you should definetly start with defining `ClothingType` and `TreatmentType` as Value Objects. I'm no Java expert but in PHP it would look like this:

```
class Cloth {

   /** @var ClothingType */
   private $type;

   /** @var TreatmentType[]|array */
   private $treatments;

   ...
}
```

Also check the Money pattern cause it might come in handy when creating your ValueObjects.

I would suggest not diving into DDD (especially in the tactical phase) without a slight understanding of it's principles. At least try to read Vaughn's DDD Distilled.

**EDIT:** Giving it a second thought I would design more or less it like this:

```
class Treatment {
    /** @var TreatmentId */
    private $treatmentId;        

    /** @var TreatmentType */
    private $type;

    /** @var Money */
    private $price;

    //constructor, getters, etc.

    public function modifyPrice(int $amount)
    {
        $this->price = new Money($amount);
    }
}

class Cloth {
     /** @var ClothType */
     private $type;

     /** @var Treatment[]|array */
     private $treatments;

     public function addTreatment(Treatment $aTreatment)
     {
         array_push($this->treatments, $aTreatment);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate (i will read the book and check the event storming). I just did DDD Fundamentals Course in Pluralsight. My bounded context involves Invoice (it's the aggregate root). I'm modeling a domain for a laundry. ClothingType must be an entity, because the user must add new ones if needed, and at the same time specify the treatments supported for the ClothingType (and the prices of course).

Comment: If you're starting from scratch I suggest you begin with the core domain - what makes the business up and going, makes it special? I wouldn't consider invoicing the part of it. You should start asking yourself what's going on when a `Customer` places his `Order` - from the beginning to the end. I guess only the `Employee` might modify `ClothingType`. If it's an entity you might consider passing `ClothingTypeId` UUID to your `Cloth` object, 'cause it's a Value Object - it's unique. Your `ClothingType` could have `ClothingTypeId, name, UserId, costModifier, createdAt, updatedAt` etc.

Comment: Thanks, what a great insight. The core domain would be ClothesTreatment, customers make ClothesTreatmentOrders in case. Only employees can create and modify new treatmet types.  How would costModifier work? How can i determine the cost of treatment type according to the cloth type choosed?

Comment: Other thing, there is other bounded context, with orders specific to them - Tailoring bc. I want to associate all orders in all bounded context in one invoice. A customer can make orders belonging to multiple bounded contexts. How to proceed in this case?

Comment: @HenrickPedro In DDD it all "depends". I still advise you to design your model first with Event Storming. If `ClothingTreatment` is your core domain then both treatments/services your bussines provides belong to the context. What does the `Customer` have to do to accomplish the task of `ClothingTreatment`? Does he `Laundry::add(Cloth $aCloth)` and then `Launder::summarize()` which traverses `Cloth` for search of `launderPrice` or `$this->clothRepository->findOneById(ClothId $aClothId)->launder()`? It all matters how you design your model first. What events occur in the domain?

Comment: After your comments i defined TreatmentOrder as my aggregate root (ClothesTreatment being the bounded context), each order has many TreatmentOrderLine where you specify the piece of clothing (value object), the cloth type, the treatment type and the treatment price. I'm thinking in retrieving first the treatment price with the help of an application service (and repository), and then set TreatmentOrderLine with this price. That's a bit of my current code: https://pastebin.com/NRF1QxQp

Comment: I can't attend to the Event Storming unfortunately (constraints about VISA and online payment in my country).

Comment: @HenrickPedro it's a book although not complete yet
https://leanpub.com/introducing_eventstorming